# SSRS 2005 - Dataset run only prompts for one parameter but there are 3

Tags: reporting-services

Working on a report with 3 parameters:

- *@DateStart* of type `DateTime`
- *@DateEnd* of type `DateTime`
- *@User* of type `Text` and is multivalued

The parameters are mapped in both the report parameters as well as the dataset.  When I attempt to 'run' the dataset, only one parameter is prompted for.

Now when I preview the report, it works as expected.

Not sure what to check.  The query works fine however.

Comment: Do you have default values set for the other two parameters?

Comment: All the parameters have default values